# Getting org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException while working with jackrabbit repository

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

```
        class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager">

        <param name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.200:5433/NEWDMS" />
        <param name="user" value="postgres" />
        <param name="password" value="eminence" />
         <param name="schema" value="postgresql" />
         <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_" />
          <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />

    </PersistenceManager>
```

I have created  a transient Repository and done changes in repository.xml  file
while accessing jackrabbit repository i am getting following exception : org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid namespace index: 3158064

Comment: Please add more detail to your question in order to get (better) answers. State an actual question and tell us http://whathaveyoutried.com. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The "failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe..." message is a symptom of a repository inconsistency.  Start with these knowledge base articles: [Fix the "jcr:system" node](http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/Crx/Troubleshooting/FixTheJcrSystemNode.html), [Consistency Check](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/upgrading/consistency-check.html), and [Tar Data File Rotation](http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/Crx/Troubleshooting/TarDataRotation.html).  The third link highlights this configuration parameter of the persistence manager that might be of interest (although I see that you are not using the default TPM persistence manager, so it might not be relevant):

```
<param name="maxFileSize" value="512" />
```